# Searching For Special Characters in postgresql

Tags: postgresql, special-characters

i am trying to find rows in a postgresql table where a specific column contains special characters excluding the following
`@^$.!\-#+'~_`

any help appreciated

Comment: Hi zarek, did you mean ALL UPPERCASE and ALL LOWERCASE text?

"ALLUPPERCASE" => true
"NOTALLuppercase" => false
"alllowecase" => true
"alllowercasebutspecial_char" => false

Maybe you can give a few examples :)

Comment: thank you for the feedback, i changed my question to make it less ambiguous.  Thanks again

Answer (score 2):

Hi I think I figured it out. I found a solution that worked for me using **[Posix Regular Expressions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-matching.html)**.

```
SELECT *
FROM TABLE_NAME
WHERE fieldName ~ '[^A-Za-z0-9@^\\$.!\-#+~_]'
```

The regular expression matches any character that is not between A-Z, a-z, 0-9 and is also not any of your whitelisted characters **^$.!-#+~_**. Notice that in the regex I had to escape the backslash and the hyphen, because they have a special meaning in regex. Maybe start by evaluating my proposed regex online with a few examples, e.g. here: https://regex101.com

Comment: Then please mark my question as correct answer.

Comment: just curious, do you have to escape `^` also?